# How to run Ubuntu fully in initramfs?

Tags: boot, boot-to-ram

I have a machine with 10 GB of RAM, and I would like to run Ubuntu on it (Debian also OK if its easier), fully in RAM in such a way: I boot from a compressed image on an USB flash disk, that is uncompressed into RAM, and then I can remove the disk from the USB slot, and use the system only with RAM, without any permanent disk.

Whenever I make any changes that I want permanent, I would put the flash disk back into the USB slot (possibly not the same one as I used initially to boot, as I would like to keep many versions of the boot flash disk), and run some command that would save the current state into a compressed image on the disk.

How can I set this up?

Comment: Heh [I asked about this last year](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1100462) but didn't get anywhere. At this rate PCI-E x16 SSDs are going to be here and affordable before I've managed this.

Comment: If you are still interested in this look into Casper, or Live-boot.

Comment: Can you confirm that the answer works?

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible using the Ubuntu desktop CD to do this without keeping the USB disk inserted the entire time.  However, given that you have a sufficient amount of RAM, you can use the `toram` casper option to copy the contents of the desktop CD into memory (by using a tmpfs).

[Startup Disk Creator [image: Startup Disk Creator]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/usb-creator) will get you most of the way there.  Just be sure to use the "stored in reserved extra space" option.  Next, edit `syslinux/txt.cfg` in the resulting USB disk and put `toram` just before the `--` in every `append` line except the one for "Check CD for defects."

Answer (score 0):

Well, aren't live cds doing this already? I use [finnix](http://www.finnix.org/), which is debian based, a lot to do mainteinance, it can boot from CD (or USB), load itself completely into RAM and free the CD slot for use.